# Azure Function Authentication using AD B2C for Daemon Applications

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-ad-b2c

I have a Azure Function App running in a Premium Plan that is authenticated using Azure AD B2C. Users of a simple SPA obtain their tokens through a *signin* flow of the AD B2C. The SPA is registered as app in the AD B2C and the Function App's Authentication is configured to use that app registration:

Authentication / Azure Active Directory / Advanced

*ClientId:* `<ClientId of the app registration>`

*Issuer Url:* `https://<ADB2C-Tenant>.b2clogin.com/<ADB2C-Tenant>.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=B2C_1_Sign_In`

Calls against the Function App with these tokens obtained throught the SPA work fine.

Now, I need a daemon applications (at the moment the function itself) to access the Function App, without a user performing a login.

For this I tried obtaining the token as client credential with shared secret:

```
GET
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<B2C-Tenant-Id>/oauth2/v2.0/token?
grant_type=client_credentials
&client_id=<ClientId of the app registration>
&scope=https://<ADB2C-Tenant>.onmicrosoft.com/<ClientId of the app registration>/.default
&client_secret=<Secret of the app registration>
```

This successfully returns a JWT token, however using it to authenticate a call to the function app results in `401: You do not have permission to view this directory or page.`.

I suspect this is caused by a "false" issuer of the token: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<ADB2C-Tenant>/v2.0` as opposed to the issuer of the working JWT token: `https://<ADB2C-Tenant>.b2clogin.com/<B2C-Tenant-Id>/v2.0/`. The latter gets accepted by the Function App, the former does not.

I understand that the "OAuth 2.0 client credentials grant flow" is currently not directly supported by the Azure AD B2C [as described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/application-types#unsupported-application-types). However, the document describes a "workaround", which is from my understanding essentially what I already tried without success.

How can I get this working and access a Azure Function App protected with Azure AD B2C with Daemon Applications as well?

Comment: This is not going to work with auth setup through the portal, it only trusts one issuer. You need to do it the traditional way of adding authentication libraries to the app and have it trust two issuers. Example [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/apps/blob/master/apps/spa-hellojs/source-code/.Net-Core-API-RBAC/MultiBearerAPI/Startup.cs#L36)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Jas Suri in the comment section, We can only setup one issuer from portal. You need to use authentication libraries to trust two issuers.

Answer (score 1):

FYI Authentication v2 now supports this - you can add multiple identity providers.

Comment: I don't think we can still add multiple instance of same identity provider in function app, Azure Active Directory in this case.